# How to stop EngineServer.exe when a memory leaks happen?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-services

EngineServer, or McAfee Engine Server is a McAfee service, known for memory leaks ([documented in KB59962 here](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB59962) and [discussed here](https://community.mcafee.com/thread/4105).  It seems that the fix is installing a patch.

A workaround listed in the KB was to restart the service, however I tried using the task manager and services.msc, but it seems that access is denied (even though I am an admin). I think this is because security settings in McAfee. Any suggestion how to stop/restart it? Normally restarting the computer will work, but now I need to not restart the computer and I think the patch also need restarting in order to work ( I updated my McAfee but the memory is still high).

Any idea how to stop/restart this service to restore the memory?

Answer (score 2):

I have been having this issue for ages, and I also tried killing the process in Task Manager but it wouldn't let me. What I ended up doing was opening the McAfee Virusscan Console, disabling all the modules, and then killing `engineserver.exe`

My experience with McAfee is that it has been nothing but trouble.

Answer (score -1):

I could only suggest you abandon McAfee and go with [Microsoft Security Essentials.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/products/security-essentials)

It's -

- Free
- Very light on the resources
- Good for Rootkits
- Updates through Windows Update

It may not be the best (if you don't trust MSE, get [Avast!](http://www.avast.com/) or use MSE in combination with something like [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/)) but it's better than paying for resource hogs.

If you're intent on McAfee, look through services (you can find it in Windows search, "services") it's the one with the cog icon. Be sure to google services to see if they're vital to stability.

Comment: Hi zeta, as explained in the question, I tried that and services cannot stop it because access denied or something